# Retrieve Data from fb Realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

can you help me to display the name of the user in my profile fragment please ? i tried many times, but no success, it took me almost 2 weeks and still can't.

here is the code of ***profile fragment*** :

```
private TextView mName, mDesc;


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    mDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Userss");

    retrieveuserinfo();

    settings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(this);


    return view;
}

private void retrieveuserinfo() {
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                String username = users.getUsername();


                mName.setText(username);



            }
```

here you got my realtime database structure
[image]

here you got my User.class

```
public class Users {

     String userId;
     String username;
     String usergenre;

    public Users() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getUsergenre() {
        return usergenre;
    }

    public Users(String userId, String username, String usergenre) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.usergenre = usergenre;
```

Comment: What does `Users.class` look like?

Comment: @Blundell i've updated the post and i putted user.class inside check it

Comment: "still can't" so what happens, does it crash? does it display anything?

Comment: it display literally nothing ! the username is blank @Blundell

Comment: try `getReference("Userss");` instead of `getReference().child("Userss");`

Comment: thank you, i've tried it, but it doesn't work, my username is blank in my device..

Comment: Ahve you tried to log the error in `onCancelled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your actual user json to your User object, not all the objects under `Userss`

i.e.

instead of:

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Users users = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
```

try:

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Users users = postSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work, can you check my last comment please ? i've drop there the entire code ; )

Comment: Your `User` is under a unique ID, `LkMM92Cg2y9PXpw16w` you need to figure out how to reference that. For instance something like `postValue.get("LkMM92Cg2y9PXpw16w").getValue(Users.class)` thats just a guess, you need to read the actual firebase documentation for reads

Answer (score 0):

ok, well it still doesn't display anything, so i think that i will post more clearly the code for you :

**

- profile fragment (where i want to display the name)

**

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button settings;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private TextView mName, mDesc;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        mName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Userss");

        retrieveuserinfo();

        settings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.settings);
        settings.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
    }

    private void retrieveuserinfo() {
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Users users = postSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);


                    String username = users.getUsername();
                    mName.setText(username);



                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

**Users class :**

```
public class Users {

     String userId;
     String username;
     String usergenre;

    public Users() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getUsergenre() {
        return usergenre;
    }

    public Users(String userId, String username, String usergenre) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.usergenre = usergenre;
    }
}
```

**My database structure :**

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Nwu.png)